# Heroku build of Vue app failing due to a (incorrectly) missing file. Why?

Tags: javascript, heroku, vue.js

guys. I'm having a rather bizarre issue when deploying a Vue app (with a Node/Express backend) to heroku. The build fails, as seen in the linked image, as a result of the Signup.vue file in the views folder not being detected from the router.js file. Why is this unexpected? Because I have the Signup.vue file alongside other relevant project's view files in the views folder, and the latter are being detected. How do I know this? Well, the (heroku) build is successful when I comment out the Signup route part in the router.js file. Also, I have tried a manual build of Vue app just to be sure if it's successful and indeed it is. So, what gives?

Not sure if the project structure is relevant but I've also included an image of it.

**Build Error Message**
[image]

**Project (client) Structure**

[image]

Comment: Any chance you might have forgotten to commit the file?

Comment: @Psidom No, not really. I did commit it. This is really weird!